# RxJS batch HTTP requests in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
const mynums = [[1,2], [3,4]] // this array may contain any number of integer arrays
```

Using this I want to make the following HTTP requests:

```
http://myserver.com/resource/1 // 2 requests made simultaneously
http://myserver.com/resource/2

http://myserver.com/resource/3 // 2 requests made simultaneously but only after first 2 complete
http://myserver.com/resource/4
```

I know I can use forkJoin like so:

```
forkJoin([
  this.http.get('http://myserver.com/resource/1')
  this.http.get('http://myserver.com/resource/2')
]).subscribe(
  (responses) => {
    console.log(responses[0])
    console.log(responses[1])
  }
)
```

But how would I do this to batch HTTP requests to accommodate for the `mynums` array, which is of variable length and to ensure that the first batch of requests completes before the 2nd batch of requests is made? and allow for a 3rd or 4th batch also or N batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
source = from([[1,2], [3,4]]);

source
.pipe(
  map(idies => idies.map(id => "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + id)),
  concatMap(urls => forkJoin(...urls.map(url => this.http.get(url))))
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

whole code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-batch-angular?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **concatMap & forkJoin** to make other batch request once first batch gets over.

```
from(mynums).pipe( 
     concatMap (x=> {
       return forkJoin(x.map(t=>{
         return this.http.get(`http://myserver.com/resource/${t}`)
       }))
     })
).subscribe(console.log)
```

**[DEMO with batch requests](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loop-through-array-with-mergemap-forkjoin?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**